# (HTML, CSS, JS) Нет полосы прокрутки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть main c парой article выходящие за границы экрана

Ожидал появление полосы прокрутки(всей страницы)однако ее нет

Пробовал не помогло:

```
body {
overflow-y: scroll;
/*overflow: auto;*/
}
```

Код:

```
<main class="main_go">
<article>
       <div class="btn_1"> 
       </div>
</article>

<article>
        <div class="btn_1"> 
        </div>
    </article>
<article>
       <div class="btn_1"> 
       </div>
</article>

<article>
        <div class="btn_1"> 
        </div>
    </article>
</main>
```

```
.main_go {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    width: 887px;
    height: auto;
    left: calc(50% - 443px);
}
.btn_1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    
    left: 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задай
`body { height:...; box-sizing: border-box; /*если надо можно margin задать или padding*/ }`
Overflow: scroll оставь, лишним не будет
Если не помогло,напиши в коментах

Comment: Я к тому, что запись height: auto неправильная, для твоего случая нужна какая-то высота, лучше в процентах или vh

Comment: Спасибо за помощь 
Проблема была в моей невнимательности 
Я тегу main задал позицию fixed от того и не было прокрутки